# Swift import statement failing

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, twitter

**UPDATED with answer at bottom**

I am using the TwitterKit framework as installed with Twitter's new Fabric platform. This code in `ViewController.swift` works just fine:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Following
//
//  Created by David Aragon on 12/4/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 David Aragon. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import TwitterKit
```

But this code in a custom Swift file I made called `TwitterAdapter.swift` fails:

```
//
//  TwitterAdapter.swift
//  Following
//
//  Created by David Aragon on 12/10/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 David Aragon. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import TwitterKit // Error: No such module 'TwitterKit'
```

I made sure to add `TwitterAdapter.swift` to all my targets when I created it. Here are some screen shots to illuminate the directory hierarchy:

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE:**

Solved with the latter portion of Kampai's answer. Here is the part that got it all working:

> Again right click on the project name and click on Add files to
>   "project-name" >> Select TwitterKit.framework bundle and click on Add
>   button will add a reference of that framework to project.

Comment: Is the framework written in objective-C by any chance?

Comment: I'm using it successfully in `ViewController.swift` so I doubt it's an issue of interoperability.

Comment: what if you change `Foundation` to `UIKit` in `TwitterAdapter.swift`?

Comment: @Raptor Nothing changes with that unfortunately.

Comment: Sometimes simply deleting the derived data folder (`~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`) and cleaning your project can fix these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have tried to add this framework in application and its perfectly working. From this it is clear that issue is related to linking with the module you have added.

Relink / Reference again with the module will resolve this issue:

**Points need to be highlight:**

1. Copy the framework to project application folder.

For example:

Go to finder of its location >> From Xcode right click on project name >> **Show in finder** will open project location folder. Here you must have to copy `TwitterKit.framework` bundle.

[image]

2. Again right click on the project name and click on **Add files to "project-name"** >> Select `TwitterKit.framework` bundle and click on **Add** button will add a reference of that framework to project.

Comment: I am having same error but in Objective C code while trying to use the Twitter Authentication. I have installed the Fabric.framework and TwitterKit.framework using cocoapods.

Should I add it manually to the project to make it work? I will try it though. Thanks.

Comment: @RajanMaharjan For the cocoapods - you don't need to add it manually. Cocoapods are powerfull enough to solve linking issues.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I can see that TwitterKit is dependent on TwitterCore which I have not added to pod. I will add it to pod and see if it is the culprit. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I had a same error with Xcode 7

Helped to uncheck and then check again a checkbox field standing for linking the broken framework in the target membership section[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. My project was swift based and there were no objective C code. I wanted to add 3rd party framework and on import  facing same error "no such module". I solved it by adding a bridging-header file in swift and just import framework there. It works for me.