# Xcode 8 Builds Successfully but Fails on Archive

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I am writing a program in Swift using Mac OS Sierra and Xcode 8.3.2 and am using the RandomKit module from: https://github.com/nvzqz/RandomKit.  I am using the basic Swift Package Manager to import the package into my project.

My program builds and runs fine, but when I go to archive it, I get an error saying "No such module 'RandomKit'

It highlights my code:

```
import RandomKit
```

Does anyone know why this would build and run but fail when I attempt to archive?

Comment: You need to build the project successfully once before using the library.

comment `import RandomKit` -> build your project -> uncomment `import RandomKit`

Comment: or check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27414202/swift-import-statement-failing

Answer (score 1):

By default, when you *Run* in XCode, it uses the `Debug` configuration, and when you *Archive*, it uses the `Release` configuration.  In `Build Settings`, look at the `Build Active Architecture Only` setting.  By default, it is `Yes` for `Debug`, and `No` for `Release`.

This means that when you *Run*, XCode only builds for the simulator's architecture, but when you *Archive*, it builds for all possible iOS architectures.

Now, look at the settings for RandomKit to see what architectures it is built for.  It needs to include all of the iOS architectures, like `arm64`, `armv7`, and `armv7s`.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm actually building an app for Mac OS not iOS.  I went in and changed Build Active Architecture Only from No to Yes for Release and it still fails to build with the same import error.

Answer (score 1):

After probably 4 hours I finally figured it out. I think this must be a bug in Xcode, but here is my workaround.

In this folder:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<My App Name>/Build/Products/Debug
```

I found RandomKit.framework and ShiftOperations.framework.  I copied those two files into the root directory of my Xcode Project, and then linked the frameworks under General in my Xcode Project.

[Linking Frameworks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3JbC.png)